# Providing feedback with mail in android

Tags: android, email, feedback

I want to put feedback option in android app as some apps do. I presently have this code

```
Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        Email.setType("text/email");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "feedback@gmail.com" });
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Feedback");
        Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Sending Feedback:"));
```

But this code redirects to default app. As I don't want to show **to address**, I came to know that it is not possible with default in-built email app.

Later thought to implement using java api, so that I can `hardcode` my mail credentials(including username, password) and send it to the mail that I specify. So that user doesn't need to log in. Just he mentions his mail address in the given column, message. That's it. Then after clicking on send button, it should go the feedback mail id. But this is risky if some one converts my apk into source code as they would come to know my credentials that I used for this feedback. Can some one please suggest me how to implement this in a correct way so that user need not have any credentials or mail app?

**Sending mail from php:**

```
<?php
 $to = "recipient@example.com";
 $subject = "Hi!";
 $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";
 if (mail($to, $subject, $body)) {
   echo("<p>Email successfully sent!</p>");
  } else {
   echo("<p>Email delivery failed…</p>");
  }

     ?>
```

Comment: you may try considering posting your feedback data to some php script or a servlet, which later on forwards it to your mailbox.

Comment: @twntee But I can't maintain a server for that.

Comment: @well there are so many free hostings out there, one I use for same purpose is 3owl.com, I just have a PHP file there, and all the responses and feedbacks from all the websites are submitted there, which are then forwarded to my mailing address.

Comment: @twntee Thank you so much. Please add it as an answer so that I could accept. As you said, I did some search on how to send mail with php now, I got the above code which is edited in my question. Is it enough? Because I heard that sending from php directly would get the mails into spam or doesn't work correctly. Is it true?

Comment: see that's the way I have used till now, and we can always tell the mailbox that, the mail from a certain address is not a spam, also there may be better workarounds, keep looking for them too, but this method hides the mailing address, all we have to do is to post to a php page. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative way of hiding you data will be to post it to a server, i.e you may try considering posting your feedback data to some php script or a servlet, which later on forwards it to your mailbox.

There are so many free hostings out there, one I use for same purpose is [www.3owl.com](http://www.3owl.com), I just have a PHP file there, and all the responses and feedbacks from all the websites are submitted there, which are then forwarded to my mailing address.

And, about mails going to Spam, well mailbox  are intelligent these days, they can be taught what is not a spam, and what is :)

Comment: Thank you. One question, can I use servlets on this site ? or does it support only php?

Comment: that's just php bro ! :(, i too searched something for servlets as they are way secure than Php, as I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider adding a separate API altogether and use their online client to view and manage the messages you receive:

1. [Apptentive](http://www.apptentive.com/developers)
2. [LetThemVote](http://www.letthemvote.com/)
3. [Recon Instruments](http://developers.reconinstruments.com/downloads/)